# Cakephp 2 and sweetalert js not submiting form data

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I do install the javascript library [sweetalert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) to replace confirm javascript native function, into a [cakephp](https://cakephp.org) 2.5 app.

My form is not submitting data after clicking on yes button. When clicking no button i have the expected behavior, the data is not submitted.

How can i use sweet alert as a confirm native javascript function where the data is submitted if i choose the yes button ?

Here is my code :

```
    <?php
//at default.ctp :
        echo $this->Html->css(array('sweetalert/sweetalert'));
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->Html->script(array('sweetalert/sweetalert','sweetalert/sweetalert.min'));

    //at the form : 
    //echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('div'=>true, 'name'=>'save', 'value' => true, 'onclick'=>'return confirm("Confirm data editing?");'));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('div'=>true, 'name'=>'save', 'value' => true, 'onclick'=>'return isConfirm()' ));
    echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>
    <script>
        swal({
              title: "Are you sure?",
              text: "you can always edit later!",
              type: "warning",
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
              confirmButtonText: "Yes, edit the data!",
              cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
              closeOnConfirm: false,
              closeOnCancel: false
            },
            function(isConfirm) {

              if (isConfirm) {
                    console.log(isConfirm);
                    swal("Edited!", "data has been edited.", "success");
              } else {
                    console.log(isConfirm);
                    swal("Cancelo", "data has not been edited :)", "error");
              }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overrides the confirm javascript function, uses regex to find the post value stored in the html, and posts it if it is confirmed. On cancel, it does not. It can be changed for other things currently set up for delete.

```
window.confirm = function(message) {

    console.log(message);
    console.log(this.document.activeElement.outerHTML);
    var html = this.document.activeElement.outerHTML;
    var finale = false;
    var returnVal = false;

    swal({

        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'Are you sue you want to delete this item?',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'

    }).then(function() {

        var post = html.match(/(document.post_)(.*)(submit\(\);)/g);
        eval(post[0])

    }, function(dismiss) {
        if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
            swal(
                'Cancelled',
                'File was not deleted',
                'error'
            )
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling your function in the `onSubmit` value of the `form` element, plus add the `return false;` for when the user cancels.